# how to get the image from the url without downloading it but store it in a variable in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, open-uri

How to fetch the image from its URL and store it in a variable

As im having a URL of a image, i need to fetch that image and then store it in variable and display the image in the variable using the rails image tag, so how to approach this..

Thanks in advance

the method i tryed

```
require 'open-uri'

imagevar =  open(url).read

img_tag(imgvar)
```

which resulted in following error

```
ActionView::Template::Error: string contains null byte
```

so what will the correct solution to approach this

Comment: Do you mean `image_tag` ? Why doesn't `image_tag(url)` work?  Please explain the scenario better as `open(url)` makes no sense.

Comment: You don't have to store the URL unless it's in DB. I think what you meant is to assign. You can either assign the URL to a variable and then render using `image_tag` or just pass the URL to the `image_tag`.

Comment: If you did actually download the image to your server you would have to Base64 encode it (since HTML can't represent binary) and to create an image tag with a `<img src="data:image/gif;base64;<%= imagevar  %>">`. `image_tag` expects a URL so its not going to work. But this really just begs the question why you think you actually need any of this in the first place. `open-uri` should also be avoided as its a remote code execution exploit waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

To assign the URL to a variable in your `.erb`, do the following.

```
<% image_url = "<image_url>" %>
```

To render the image from the URL you can use `image_tag`

```
<%= image_tag image_url %>
```